# pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSession StateBuilder':"

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to start pyspark, and keep getting this error. I resolved it once by taking care of permissions of tmp\hive directory. But it appeared again and looks impossible to resolve

```
  Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/01/27 14:24:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using built
in-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 45, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 183, in ge
tOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gatewa
y.py", line 1133, in __call__

  File "D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSession
StateBuilder':"
```

I have tried almost everything. Can someone please help me out

Comment: Could you please post full traceback (including Java one)?

Comment: this is the full traceback when i write "pyspark" in cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://techgimmick.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/error-while-instantiating-org-apache-spark-sql-hive-hivesession-statebuilder/

This blog article, explains pretty well what is happening and what is the resolution.

It says, that issue is more likely due to your companies IT policies, which can prevent you from modifying the file permission of hive/tmp directory.

To check if you have successfully mopdified the permission use ls command instead of chmod.

If it gives you an error saying unable to establish trust, you need to contact your IT team. Or remove your system from domain and add it again, as explained by Microsoft here

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2771040/the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain